# ASP.NET MVC Web form: error 404

Tags: c#, mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core

Trabajo con ASP.NET Core 1.1 Visual Studio 2017 – EntityFramework 1.0.0 , Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.02046, SQL Server 2012 LocalDB C#
Estoy haciendo mi primera experiencia con dichas herramientas. Sigo el ejemplo ContosoUniversity desarrollado en la documentación de MS.

La aplicación (web form) trata de reservas de quirófano, es una agenda.
Tengo dos entity sets relacionados muchos a muchos.: Reservas y Profesionales, hay una entity set que resuelve la relación: ProfesionalPorReserva.

```
namespace ReservaQ.Models
{
    public class ProfesionalPorReserva
    {
        public ProfesionalPorReserva() { }
        public int ProfesionalID { get; set; }
        public int ReservaID { get; set; }
        public int RolID { get; set; }
        //Navegation props
        public Profesional Profesional { get; set; }
        public Reserva Reserva { get; set; }
        public Rol Rol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

En el esquema MVC desarrollado con scaffolding hay un controller ReservasController con sus Views Index, Create, Edit, Details, Delete.
Modifiqué el ReservasController para poder mostrar los Profesionales asignados a una Reservay su Rol (Cirujano, Ayudante, Anestesista, etc)  en el View Details. Los profesionales se presentan como una lista. Junto a cada elemento Profesional agregué un link que permite hacer un Delete de dicho profesional. Ese link envía el id del Profesional,  el id2 de la reserva y el id3 del Rol al ReservasController, Action Details, desde dicha acción se llama un método que produce el Delete del registro de esa reserva y ese profesional de la entity Set ProfesionalPorReserva. Hasta acá todo funciona bien. Al realizar el delete intento (aquí está el problema) que el controller vuelva a mostrar el View Details sin el profesional eliminado Pero en este punto me da un error 404, y muestra la Route que corresponde al Paso de la View al Controller. Si operando sobre la página vuelvo al menú principal y a Reservas/Details compruebo que el profesional ha desaparecido de la lista. No sé dónde está mi error.
Uso un entity Set auxiliar para pasar mediante ViewModel los datos al Detail.cshtml.

Código de ReservasController.cs action Details

---

```
   // GET: Reservas/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id,int? id2, int? id3)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (id2 != null)
        {
            await EliminarProfesionalAsync((int) id, (int) id2,(int) id3);
        }
        var reserva = await _context.Reservas
            .Include(r => r.ProfesionalPorReservas)
                .ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath: p => p.Profesional)
            .Include(r => r.ProfesionalPorReservas)
                .ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath: r => r.Rol)
            .Include(p => p.Paciente)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ReservaID == id);
        if (reserva == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var profesionalesRol = new List<ProfesionalRol>();
        foreach(var p in reserva.ProfesionalPorReservas)
        {
            profesionalesRol.Add(new ProfesionalRol
            { AyN = p.Profesional.AyN,EnRol = p.Rol.EnRol, Orden = .RolID,Clave=p.Profesional.ID});
            };
        ViewData["Profesionales"] = profesionalesRol.OrderBy(p => p.Orden).ToList();
        return View(reserva);
    }
```

Código de método EliminarProfesional dentro de ReservasController

---

```
private async Task EliminarProfesionalAsync(int id, int id2, int id3)
        {          
            ProfesionalPorReserva profesionalPRToDelete = new ProfesionalPorReserva()
            {   ReservaID = id2,
                ProfesionalID = id,
                RolID = id3
            };
            _context.Entry(profesionalPRToDelete).State =     EntityState.Deleted;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
         }
```

Código de View Details (parte donde aparece la lista y el link a Delete)

---

```
@model ReservaQ.Models.Reserva

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
List<ReservaQ.Models.ReservaQViewModel.ProfesionalRol> profs=ViewBag.Profesionales;}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
<h4>Reserva</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaCirugia)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FechaCirugia)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quirofano)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Quirofano)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Paciente.AyN)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Paciente.AyN)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Diagnostico)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Diagnostico)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Procedimiento)
    </dt>
    //omito algunos campos

    @* acá comienza el listado de profesionales -rol *@
    <dt>
        Profesionales
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                Profesional
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 - Rol
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in profs)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.AyN -- @item.EnRol
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Details" 
                        asp-route-id="@item.Clave" 
                        asp-route-id2="@Model.ReservaID" 
                        asp-route-id3="@item.Orden">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </dd>
    @* acá termina *@
</dl>
</div>
<div>
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ReservaID">Edit</a> |
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Mensaje de error obtenido

---

No se puede encontrar esta página (localhost)
No se ha encontrado ninguna página web para la dirección
http://localhost:50184/Reservas/Details/1?id2=20&id3=1.
•   Busca localhost 50184 Reservas Details en Google
HTTP ERROR 404

---

1 es el id del profesional
20 es el id de la reserva
1 es el Rol del profesional

Esa entity (1,20,1) ha sido eliminada del Entity Set ProfesionalPorReserva

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola si tienes el controlador basado en **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** puedes decorarlo con el atributo:

```
[Route("api/Reservas")]
public class ReservasController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}/reserva/{id2}/rol/{id3}")]
    public async Task Details(int? id, int? id2, int? id3){
    ...
    }
}
```

URL:http://localhost:53641/api/reservas/5/reserva/9/rol/9

Si utilizas Controller basado en **System.Web.Mvc**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Nombre de aplicación", "Details", "Reservas", new { id = 5, id2= 6, id3 =9 }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

**Controller**

```
public class ReservasController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id, int? id2, int? id3)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**URL:** http://localhost:53620/Reservas/Details/5?id2=6&id3=9

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Intenté las dos soluciones, la segunda no me admite (IntellitSense) el using. 
Implementé la primera solución (no pude pegar el código).

Pero me da la siguiente respuesta que me confunde:
AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

ReservaQ.ReservasController.Index (ReservaQ)
ReservaQ.ReservasController.Create (ReservaQ)
ReservaQ.ReservasController.Edit (ReservaQ)
ReservaQ.ReservasController.Delete (ReservaQ)

Answer (score 2):

El problema es una desprolijidad de mi parte. Los argumentos no se corresponden con los parámetros. estaban intercambiados id e id2. Ya quedó resuelto.

Comment: podrías aceptar esta respuesta, así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D